# Moving a set of names from Excel to VBA in an array, then using it as a wildcard filter parameter

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a list in Excel. This list is ever-growing, ever-changing, and is currently defined with a

```
   ListbyName =offset(A1,0,0,counta(A1:A200),1)
```

Ok, great. Now, I get reports where I need to pull only the elements from the list to a second report. Simply dropping all of the data then filtering isn't workable, since it can only be the "essential" data that moves over. Ok, fine:

```
Dim listbyName As Variant
Set listbyName = Range("ListbyName")
   Set CSTab = CSReport.Sheets(1)
    LastRowCS = CSTab.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    CSTab.Range("$A$1:$W$100").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=listbyNumber, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Set RngCS = CSTab.Range("A1:W" & LastRowCS).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)             RngCS = RngCS.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Set CabReport.Sheets("CS").Range("C1").Resize(RngCS.Rows.Count).Value = RngCS.Value
```

Now, where I'm struggling for a bit is the next step - I need to wildcard each entry in the array when filtering for it. So instead of the data being "Apples, Oranges, Potatoes", and I'm looking to get just the apples and oranges, it's "This product contains Apples", "May have Oranges in it" "Apple", etc. How can I put wildcards around each entry in the array, so that when it filters for that entry, it finds everything?

A second example would be, in ugly brute-force manner, of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$71").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*Apples*", Criteria2:="=*Oranges*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But flexible enough to accommodate additional add-ons.

How can I get wildcards in my filters? And is my method of grabbing data, filtering it, and pasting it workable, or have I made a fundamental mistake somewhere along the line?

Edit: It's also unhappy with my filter method, error 1004.

Comment: You can only use *up to two wildcard criteria* in `Autofilter`. When more is required, you need to use the `Advanced Filter`.

Comment: *"It's also unhappy with my filter method,"*, yes in the second form, use `Operator:=xlOr`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I can work around that. I keep getting various errors when I'm trying to run it without the wildcards, would you know anything about that?

Comment: `Criteria1:=FundlistbyNumber` did you mean `listbyName`?

Comment: Pardon, yes - I did some editing to cut down on clutter and make it easier to read. I missed editing that line.

Comment: Are you still getting errors? If so please post the error message and at which line it occurs.